# Cycle Through Images in Directory and Assign a Variable to Each result in Python

Tags: python, image, for-loop

So I am trying to cycle through a set of images in a directory and I'm looking to save the output of each calculate as it's own variable, in this case d1, d2, and d3.  For some reason, this only outputs d3 and none of the other values.  Any help regarding what is wrong would be greatly appreciated!

```
filelist = ['IMG_1.jpg','IMG_2.jpg', 'IMG_3.jpg']

for imagefile in filelist:
     for i in range(1,4):
          t=Image.open(imagefile).convert('L')

arr = array(t) #Convert test image into an array
f = arr + c #Add the corrective factor to the array with the UBM
f[f > 150] = 0
value = np.sum(f) #Sum elements in array
con = np.count_nonzero(f) #Count number of nonzero elements

arraysDict = {}
arraysDict['d{0}'.format(i)] = value/con

print arraysDict
```

If I do it this way (below), it prints each value for d1, d2, and d3 but they are the same for some reason.

```
filelist = ['IMG_1604.jpg','IMG_1605.jpg', 'IMG_1606.jpg']

for imagefile in filelist:
    t=Image.open(imagefile).convert('L')   
    arr = array(t) #Convert test image into an array
    f = arr + c #Add the corrective factor to the array with the UBM
    f[f > 150] = 0 
    value = np.sum(f) #Sum elements in array
    con = np.count_nonzero(f) #Count number of nonzero elements

arraysDict = {}
for i in range(1,4):
    arraysDict['d{0}'.format(i)] = value/con

q = arraysDict.values()
print q
```

Comment: It seems like "t" would be the last thing in the list always. Is the code above formatted correctly?

Comment: It is formatted in my code correctly, however, it did not translate over.  No matter where I place t at in the loop though, it always outputs d3 and not the other variables

Comment: So are the lines below `t=Image.open(imagefile).convert('L')` indented to form part of the loop? From what you say it seems like they might not be.

Comment: I believe arraysDict needs to be defined outside of all the loops.

Comment: I will try to define arraysDict outside of the loops and yes, the lines below "t" are intended to be a part of the loop since it is converts each individual image into an array and then performs a calculation and should cycle on to the next image.

Comment: You are doing the same mistake again. Your value and con should be an array to store calculated values of each image and then you need to loop through it. Right now for each image the value and con gets initialised and only the values for d3 is stored in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initialising the `arraysDict = {}` every time inside the `for` loop. Which will clear the old data. Just initialize the `arraysDict = {}` outside the for loop.

```
filelist = ['IMG_1.jpg','IMG_2.jpg', 'IMG_3.jpg']

arraysDict = {}
value = {}
con = {}
i = 1

for imagefile in filelist:
      t=Image.open(imagefile).convert('L')
      arr = array(t) #Convert test image into an array
      f = arr + c #Add the corrective factor to the array with the UBM
      f[f > 150] = 0
      value[i] = np.sum(f) #Sum elements in array
      con[i] = np.count_nonzero(f) #Count number of nonzero elements
      i += 1


arraysDict = {}
for i in range(1,4):
    arraysDict['d{0}'.format(i)] = value[i]/con[i]

q = arraysDict.values()
print q
```

Comment: The "print" line can likely be unindented but otherwise I think this is what is desired.

Comment: I get an output like this for some reason:
`{'d1': 104.3463503649635}{'d2': 104.3463503649635, 'd1':104.3463503649635}{'d2': 104.3463503649635, 'd3':104.3463503649635, 'd1': 104.3463503649635}{'d2':104.3463503649635, 'd3': 104.3463503649635, 'd1':58.112990936555889}{'d2': 58.112990936555889, 'd3': 104.3463503649635, 'd1': 58.112990936555889}{'d2': 58.112990936555889, 'd3': 58.112990936555889, 'd1': 58.112990936555889}{'d2': 58.112990936555889, 'd3': 58.112990936555889, 'd1': 31.176130952380952}{'d2': 31.176130952380952, 'd3': 58.112990936555889, 'd1': 31.176130952380952}...'